# Cannot convert from out System.Guid? to System.Guid

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to parse string into nullable guid. Depending on the TryParse result nullable guid should store value or be null.

```
private Guid? GetData()
{
    string carName = "Volvo";
    Guid? data = Guid.TryParse(carName, out data) ? (Guid?)data : null;
    
    return data;
}
```

I'm getting a compile-time error on `out data` with message

> Cannot convert from out System.Guid? to System.Guid

Comment: `Guid? data = Guid.TryParse(carName, out var parsed) ? parsed : null;`

Comment: TryParse method does not accept the second argument as nullable type so you need to parse a specific one first and then use this in your condition:
`Guid? data = Guid.TryParse(carName, out Guid outputData) ? outputData : null;`

Comment: @yemo `var` will infer the type to be `Guid` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a different variable name:

```
Guid? data = Guid.TryParse(carName, out Guid _data) ? (Guid?)_data : null;
```

Currently, you use `data` for both

- the end result (a `Guid?`) and
- the `out` parameter of `TryParse` (which needs to be a `Guid`, not a `Guid?`).

Comment: the name _data does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user1765862 `out var _data`

Answer (score 1):

Lets make it simple and logical, and readable

```
if (Guid.TryParse(carName, out Guid g)
    return g;
return null;
```

if 3 lines bother you

```
return Guid.TryParse(carName, out Guid g) ? g : (Guid?)null;
```

Comment: I like the 3 lines best for sure. It shows the intent well while the one-liner is hard to read.

Comment: Exactly! sometimes people give answers with complex linq while a developer may be needs to understand a logical flow. For production code, sometimes it is better to have an extra line or 2 for the sake of clarity -you're right

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to not do so much in one line. This will make it easier to read and understand.

```
private Guid? GetData()
    {
        string carName = "Volvo";
        // First try to parse the string into a guid
        var canParse = Guid.TryParse(carName, out var data);

        // Return either the converted value or null
        return canParse ? data : null;
    }
```